# Where to find the elder scroll I picked up earlier

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've found the elder scroll in the tower of mzark. I went to the throat of the mountain and attempted to read it but it's no where to be found in my inventory. I know for sure I got it out of the tower because my objective tells me to talk to the dragon. Help?

Comment: Have you tried talking to the dragon?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I got to the mountain he started speaking to me and I looked through my inventory and seen no scroll. Does septumis have the scroll because I gave the cube back to him to decode some Box.

Answer (score 2):

If you're playing on a PC, you can use a console command to spawn the scroll into your inventory, as referenced in Bugs on the [UESP page for the related quest.](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Elder_Knowledge)

Open the console and type:

```
player.additem 2d513 1
```

You should then be able to read the scroll and continue the quest.

If you're on a console, unfortunately, your only options are to return to the tower in the hopes that you somehow left it there, or reload an earlier save.

Answer (score -2):

If you are playing on console, it will appear in the misc section in your inventory.

Comment: If it appears in the Misc. tab on console, it **will** appear there on PC. No difference. But your answer is still low quality. Try adding more helpful information.